# Loop through an string and build a json array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following json string returned from a shopping cart request.

```
[{"id":19,"name":"Memory","display_name":"Memory","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/19\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/19\/values"}},{"id":20,"name":"Add Keyboard & Mouse","display_name":"Add Keyboard & Mouse","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/20\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/20\/values"}},{"id":21,"name":"Monitor","display_name":"Monitor","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/21\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/21\/values"}},{"id":22,"name":"Operating System","display_name":"Operating System","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/22\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/22\/values"}},{"id":23,"name":"AntiVirus","display_name":"AntiVirus","type":"RB","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/23\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/23\/values"}}]
```

I need to loop through the above and extract each value of id"

I then call another url for each value.
This will return a json string (for id=19):

```
[{"id":73,"option_id":19,"label":"1GB DDR2 RAM (default)","sort_order":0,"value":"1GB DDR2 RAM (default)"},{"id":74,"option_id":19,"label":"2GB DDR2 RAM (+ $15.00)","sort_order":1,"value":"2GB DDR2 RAM (+ $15.00)"}]
```

And id = 20

```
[{"id":75,"option_id":20,"label":"No (Default)","sort_order":0,"value":"No (Default)"},{"id":76,"option_id":20,"label":"Yes (+$18)","sort_order":1,"value":"Yes (+$18)"}]
```

I now need to combine all these and echo out as a json array.

So questions are.
1. How do I convert the first into an array and loop through.
2. Combine all the strings returned into one json array.

MrWarby

Comment: Use `json_decode()`/`json_encode()` for this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched Google or php.net?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $firstJSONArray = json_decode('[{"id":19,"name":"Memory","display_name":"Memory","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/19\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/19\/values"}},{"id":20,"name":"Add Keyboard & Mouse","display_name":"Add Keyboard & Mouse","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/20\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/20\/values"}},{"id":21,"name":"Monitor","display_name":"Monitor","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/21\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/21\/values"}},{"id":22,"name":"Operating System","display_name":"Operating System","type":"S","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/22\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/22\/values"}},{"id":23,"name":"AntiVirus","display_name":"AntiVirus","type":"RB","values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/23\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/23\/values"}}]');

    $finalArray = array();

    foreach ($firstJSONArray as $record) {
        $itemID = $record->id;

        // get data for each ID from your API like you have given example of 18 and 19 and store the push data to final array

        $finalArray[] = "json_data_from_api_for_particular_id";
    }

    echo json_encode($finalArray);
```

Comment: Got it working thanks. I used  (in the loop)   $curlProductData = str_replace("[","",$curlProductData);
    $curlProductData = str_replace("]",",",$curlProductData);
    $finalString = $finalString.$curlProductData;

    }Then outside the loop
    $finalString = substr_replace($finalString ,"",-1);
    $finalString = '['.$finalString.']';
This gave me the format I required.
    echo $finalString;

Answer (score 1):

1. use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
2. use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

In case your version of PHP is older and does not have these functions, the comments in the above pages refer to alternative implementations.

Approximately:

```
$inJSON = <<<EOF
[
{"id":19,"name":"Memory","display_name":"Memory","type":"S",
  "values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/19\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/19\/values"}},
{"id":20,"name":"Add Keyboard & Mouse","display_name":"Add Keyboard & Mouse","type":"S",
  "values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/20\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/20\/values"}},
{"id":21,"name":"Monitor","display_name":"Monitor","type":"S",
  "values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/21\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/21\/values"}},
{"id":22,"name":"Operating System","display_name":"Operating System","type":"S",
  "values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/22\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/22\/values"}},
{"id":23,"name":"AntiVirus","display_name":"AntiVirus","type":"RB",
  "values":{"url":"https:\/\/store-v035aw9.mybigcommerce.com\/api\/v2\/options\/23\/values.json","resource":"\/options\/23\/values"}}
]
EOF;

$decode = json_decode($inJSON);
foreach ($decode as $key => $item) {
   echo "Id:" . $item->id . "\n";
}
```

Incidentally, the JSON output for each URL call you intend to make seems to indicate that it returns a JSON array. Can't you make a single URL call with all the id values you need to get **all** the items you want to send back? Multiple requests to a second server can have performance issues and reducing this to one call will avoid the need to join the multiple responses together.

Otherwise you will have to

1. remove the leading and trailing [ ] from the strings you get back
2. join them all together

   $finalResponse = '[' . join( ',', $responses) . ']';